# Eclipse Junit how to default vm args without editing JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

My project uses a test profile in Maven.  When I run the unit tests in eclipse I need to pass a VM arg to replicate the profile settings.  I have read that you can edit the JRE to add these arguments, but I'd prefer not to edit the JRE.

Is there a project level setting in Eclipse to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the arguments to the Run Configuration(s), but that can be tedious if you use a lot of different run configs to run tests (eg, if you run different test classes or packages of tests individually).

Another option is to create an alternate JRE configuration that you use just for running tests. It can point to the same physical location as your "main" JRE, just give it a different name and add the VM args you need. Then assign that JRE to the test run configuration(s).

[image]

Comment: I don't see how that offers you anything as opposed to adding the args to the run config since you will have to create the run config for the class and then change the default JRE anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No this must be done in the Run Configuration if you want to run the JUnit Test with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the Run Configuration settings. You can also setup at JRE level in order to default.

Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs. Select the JRE you're using, click Edit, and there will be a line for Default VM Arguments which will apply to every execution. For instance, I use this on OSX to hide the icon from the dock, increase max memory and turn on assertions: -Xmx512m -ea -Djava.awt.headless=true

[image: Check this image for variables]

Comment: Would these default VM arguments carry over to other projects that use this JRE?